# Get null data when reading from a valid path

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator

I use the iOS Simulator to test.

When select photos from its own library and store the paths to a database backed by mongodb and nodejs, I then tried to read from the path and reload the image data:

```
NSString *photo1Path = photo1[0];

NSLog(@"!!!photo1Path: %@", photo1Path); 
// Console: !!!photo1Path: /var/folders/x4/01z7j18d7vz8rxrgcxt2w9dm0000gn/T/6-vZsBlMzA1Lj_pkdVYRx-HI.png

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:photo1Path ];

NSLog(@"!!!photo1Data: %@", data);
// Console: !!!photo1Data: (null)

UIImage *photo1Image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[self.photo1Button setImage:photo1Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

As you can see from the above, the path is correct but the data is read to be "null". I tried to search solutions online but still feel confused. Is it a problem of iOS simulator or do I need to use the main bundle or something?

Comment: Are you sure you have access to the given folder? Note that absolute file path can change. You should always create path relative to your current document directory.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes from the terminal, I can navigate and access to that file. It's there. This path is generated automatically by Xcode. Do you mean that I should read and write the data to a new location under my current dir?

Comment: Every iOS app can access only the files in its own folders - documents, cached and temporary. It cant access files outside its own folders.